# About android records

Tags: android

evice Type,Brand Name,Marketing Name,OS,OS Version,Device Model,User Given Name,Device Last Location,Gaia ID
MOBILE,Motorola,moto g 5G - 2023,Android,13,moto g 5G - 2023,Motorola Moto G 5G - 2023,"Country ISO: US
Last Activity Time: 2023-09-07 08:19:04 UTC",282797937612
MOBILE,Apple,iPhone 13 Pro,iOS,16.6,"iPhone14,2",iPhone,"Country ISO: US
Last Activity Time: 2023-09-07 05:07:54 UTC",282797937612
TV,,,Linux,,V555-H1,,,282797937612
PC,,,Mac,10.15.7,,,"Country ISO: US
Last Activity Time: 2023-08-26 18:12:05 UTC",282797937612
What is this

I don’t know what this is

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.